# Extract region from a Curvilinear satellite Dataset

Tags: python-2.7, hdf, satellite

I have satellite swath data from MODIS and need to extract a subset (region) of data to analyze (NOT PLOT). I am trying to find the best way to do this with out loops which can be slow.  In the past I have used set.intersect but this does not work on 2D data.

My issue is both Lat and Lon are 2D and I need to find the indices where my conditions are met (lat>=x1)&(lat<=x2) and similar for lon. and then use those 2D indices to slice my main data set (Aerosol Optical Depth)

Latitude Sample[image: Latitude Sample]

Longitude Sample[image: Longitude Sample]

Aerosol MetaData[image: Aerosol Metadata]

Code so Far [image: Code]

Normally (for 1D lat/lon) I would used Opt_Depth_Land[:,goodlat,goodlon] to extract my data but this does not work for this type of data set.

Any Help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

```
    valid_lat=(lat>=user_lat-radius)&(lat<=user_lat+radius)
    valid_lon=(lon>=user_lon-radius)&(lon<=user_lon+radius)
    Valid_Coord=np.where((valid_lat==True)&(valid_lon==True))
```